# Problem occured while installing Ubuntu 14.04 - Package authentication failed

Tags: system-installation, bug-reporting, debugging

[image]

As you can see this is the syslog from my installation of ubuntu 14.04 and the authentication of the initramfs-tools package faild. I have 2 questions here

1. How could that be?
2. Where can I report this bug?

Comment: I did no because this is the syslog of a normal installation from the official ubuntu mini iso. so I hven't done anything then booting up this is o and started the installation

Comment: Oh, didn't notice the installation part. What mirror did you pick?

Comment: de.archive.ubuntu.com